# jquery prevent closing dialog when clicking on overlay

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, overlay, modal-dialog

I've an application with some modal dialogs. When I click on overlay, those dialogs automatically close. I want to prevent this behaviour and let them close only if I click on a specific button, which works properly. How can I manage this?

The overlay is automatically created in the following div:

```
<div class="ui-widget-overlay" 
 style="height: 100%; width: 100%; position: fixed; 
 left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 2001; opacity: 0.3;">
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you create a fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
$('.ui-widget-overlay').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

If that should fail, perhaps try:

```
window.onload = function() {
    $('.ui-widget-overlay').off('click');
}
```

Comment: the event of click is fired only if the selector is
$('.ui-widget-overlay') without "div."
But that seems not working, I've already tried to "prevent default"
Thanks anyway

Comment: and what's the code that actually closes that overlay? is it a plugin? can't you update it to react on key events only?

Comment: I'm modifying a project which uses jquery-ui and jqgrid. As I said, event is fired but preventDefault seems not working because modal dialogs are automatically closed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

```js
$("#yourmodal").dialog({
  closeOnEscape: false,
  /*This will disable keyboard*/
  resizable: false,
  modal: true,
  show: {
    effect: "fade",
    duration: 100
  },
  open: function() {
    $('.ui-widget-overlay').click(function(e) {
      /*This will disable click and close*/
      e.preventDefault();
      return false;
    });
  },
  close: function() {},
  position: {
    my: "center",
    at: "center",
    collision: "fit"
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#yourmodal").dialog({
  closeOnEscape: false,
  resizable: false,
  modal: true,
  open: function() {
    $('.ui-widget-overlay').css('pointer-events', 'none')
  },
  close: function() {}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not set the CSS `pointer-events: none` to an overlay. It would not make your overlay cancel the "click" event. Instead it would make the overlay "transparent" to all the events allowing the events to "[fall though](https://robertnyman.com/2010/03/22/css-pointer-events-to-allow-clicks-on-underlying-elements/)" the overlay.

If that's what you wanted to get then go ahead.
Otherwise stop the "click" event propagation using `Event.stopImmediatePropagation` as in the example below.

```
$("#yourmodal").dialog({
  closeOnEscape: false,
  open: function() {
            $(".ui-widget-overlay")
                .off("click").on("click", function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    e.stopImmediatePropagation(); // this line is the key. "e.stopPropagation()" wouldn't be enough.
                });
  },
  close: function() {}
});
```